# Add web part in master page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How to add a web part in a master page in [SPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Designer) in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a web part in a master page you have to add the web part between some HTML Tags like `<TD> ,<Div> or place holder` . Select the appropriate area in the master page where you want to add the web part, then click insert in top menu, select SharePoint controls under it, and select webparts. Drag and drop the required web part from the new webpart menu displayed in the right pane to the desired location in the master page.